# Sending a normal message after a slash command is run

Tags: python, discord, nextcord

Im trying to make my discord.py bot send a normal message after a user runs a certain slash command. Ive tried looking for others with this issue, but none of them are using nextcord. Im using nextcord, in a cog. Any help is appreciated.

I tried things like `interaction.send`, `interaction.send_message`, `self.bot.send_message`, and others like that. All of them resulted in errors like "Interaction has no type "send_message".

Comment: You should show us the code you have tried. Beyond that your problem statement is underspecified. Also, it seems like you are asking for help writing software that is deliberately designed to behave in a malicious manner. If that isn't the case you should edit your question to make it clear you are not asking for help being a hacker.

Comment: The question doesn't seem malicious at all, moreover its a regular question asked many times
@KurtisRader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick disclaimer: I am using discord.py, but this should work for nextcord too.

If you have an `Interaction`, you can get the channel from it and then use `send` to send a message in there.

```py
await interaction.channel.send("whatever")
```

Or, you could also use `followup` to send messages with a Webhook:

```py
await interaction.followup.send("whatever")
```

Docs: https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/stable/api.html?highlight=interaction#nextcord.Interaction

Hope this helps.